# update an object in django model

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have a model in my app named `foo`

```
class foo(models.Model):
    a = models.CharField(max_length=500, default=0,null=True)
    a_quantity = models.CharField(max_length=500, default=0, null=True)
```

and I am updating this model from another form like this:

```
 def form_valid (self, form):
        product = form.save(commit=False)
        product.save()
        data = form.cleaned_data
        for i in range(1, 9):
            foo.objects.update_or_create(a=data["a" + str(i)],
                                                     b=data["a_quantity" + str(i)])
```

But the problem here is that it creates a new entry if `a` is same but `a_quantity`. I want that when a is repeated its quantity should be summed to the existing quantity in the model.

For eg id my input is this:

```
bar     10
```

and the table is like this:

```
a   a_quantity

nar  27
bar  15
lar  10
```

then when the function is called it should do this:

```
a   a_quantity

nar  27
bar  25
lar  10
```

Currently it creates a new entry with the same name and different quantity.
How can I do this ?

Comment: I assume that `bar` should have value `10`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I edited the question.. actually bar value should change to 25 as it was already 15

Comment: if you aim to increment the value, then this is not an `.update_or_create(..)` since the update is *not* the same as the `.create(..)`. Then you will need to perform an `.update(..)` and in case that returns `0` rows matching, you might want to create a new entry.

Comment: Yes I want to increment the value, how do i do that ?

Answer (score 2):

You set the update value in the `defaults=…` parameter of the [**`.update_or_create(..)`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create):

```
for i in range(1, 9):
    foo.objects.update_or_create(
        a=data['a' + str(i)],
        defaults={'a_quantity': data['a_quantity' + str(i)])}
    )
```

or you can increment the value with the given `a_quantity` with:

```
from django.db.models import F

for i in range(1, 9):
    foo.objects.filter(
        a=data['a' + str(i)]
    ).update(
        a_quantity=F('a_quantity')+data['a_quantity' + str(i)]
    )
```

I'm however not sure that this is a good idea, since one often aims to make requests *idempotent*. We can create a record in case no object to update exists:

```
from django.db.models import F

for i in range(1, 9):
    exists = foo.objects.filter(
        a=data['a' + str(i)]
    ).update(
        a_quantity=F('a_quantity')+data['a_quantity' + str(i)]
    )
    if not exists:
        foo.objects.create(a=data['a' + str(i)], a_quantity=data['a_quantity' + str(i)])
```

Some remarks:

1. It might make more sense to define the `a` field as a non-NULLable *unique* field;
2. normally a model is written in `PerlCase`, so `Foo`, not <s>`foo`</s>;
3. you might want to use `'a_quantity{}'.format(i)` over constructing strings;
4. using a `range(..)` might not be the best option here, since if there are less than nine updates, it will raise an error, and if there are more, these will not be handled.

Comment: the filtering and update would work only if `bar` is present in the model but what if a totally new entry is passed ?

Comment: What is F here and what does it do ? and also please explain the `):` in exists

Comment: @RahulSharma: an `F` object encapsulated a reference to a field, for example to add a value to the value already present in that field: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.F

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you need this:

```
for i in range(1, 9):
        foo.objects.update_or_create(a=data["a" + str(i)],
                                                     b=data["a_quantity" + str(i)])
```

Maybe we could better help you if you show us your `forms.py`.

Do not `save()` the product if you don't want to save it.
Assuming that `bar` value should be 25 instead of 15 as you've shown in the example, you can use [`get_or_create`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) instead:

```
def form_valid (self, form):
    data = form.cleaned_data
    product, created = foo.objects.get_or_create(
                         a=data['a'],
                         defaults={'a_quantity': 0}
                       )
    product.a_quantity += data['a_quantity']
    product.save()
```

First a product is created with quantity as 0 if it does not exist, otherwise it is retrieved. Next, the quantity is updated.

A better option would be to use [F expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions) here instead. This avoids race conditions and inconsistency when multiple people try to update the same object instance.

```
from django.db.models import F

def form_valid (self, form):
    data = form.cleaned_data
    product, created = foo.objects.get_or_create(
                         a=data['a'],
                         defaults={'a_quantity': 0}
                       )
    product.a_quantity = F('a_quantity') + data['a_quantity']
    product.save()
```